# Progress hide json fields

Tags: json, progress-4gl, openedge

I'm using Progress OpenEdge.

I've created a dataset and nested a few temp-tables. I put in specific fields in order to relate the temp-tables.

In xml if you want to hide the fields that you use to relate the temp-tables you would use xml-node-type "HIDDEN" next to the field where you defined the temp-table.

So when you view the xml document after "dataset handle":write-xml("whatever-paramters"). The relation fields aren't seen.

The question...

How do I do the same with json?

I can't find anything that would resemble xml's xml-node-type "HIDDEN".

Answer (score 6, accepted):

See the SERIALIZE-HIDDEN attribute.

http://knowledgebase.progress.com/articles/Article/000048926